# Why is octave parsing this string to give two numbers to a single value?

Tags: octave

In the octave session below, why is a simple `strread` operation displaying two numbers for A and B (instead of just one)?

```
octave:43> mystring = '18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1 "foo bar baz"'
octave:43> [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H] = strread(mystring, '%f %d %f %f %f %f %d %d %*f')
A =

    18
   NaN

B =

  8
  0

C =  307
D =  130
E =  3504
F =  12
G = 70
H = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify how many times to repeat the provided format, it is reading until it hits the end of your string. The `%*f` consumes `"foo`, the first `%f` consumes `bar` and the `%d` consumes `baz"`. Since neither of those can be properly processed as numbers, they result in unexpected results.

You can specify the number of repeats to use as the second input parameter to force it to only attempt to read one copy.

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H] = strread(mystring, '%f %d %f %f %f %f %d %d %*f', 1)
```

Alternately you can modify your format string to accomodate the strings at the end of the line

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H] = strread(mystring, '%f %d %f %f %f %f %d %d %*s %*s %*s')
```